# XML feed 503 error

Tags: php, xml, timeout

Is it possible when I get a 503 error from a XML stream to not have it stop the PHP script but instead try again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question could benefit from some more context, but assuming you mean the HTTP Status Code 503 you can try with

```
do {
    $feed = simplexml_load_file('http://example.com/rss.xml');
} while (strpos($http_response_header[0], '503') !== false);

// do something with $feed now
```

This will repeat the [`do` block](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php) as long as the server [responded](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php) with a 503 Status Code.